# Initial iptable rule and knockd operation in vps

Tags: debian, security, iptables, firewall, vps

Today I launched a vps with Debian 7 x64 and started playing around with it.
I installed xampp as well as knock daemon to get my hands dirty. So, all I wanted to do was to actually block all requests sent from anywhere to any port except when heading to port 80. Furthermore, I would like to be able to send some "random" tcp hits to some ports and the right combination of them to unlock just for me the port 4555 which is for ssl as I changed the default one, port 22.
So, I have been testing all day long many rules in iptables but didn't had luck.
To be more specific, I am able to open port 4555 after hitting tcp ports 7000, 8000 and 9000, which are the default ports from knockd settings.

```
sudo knock -v A.B.C.D 7000 8000 9000
```

Checking if rules applied, with `iptables -L`, and it's all ok. My ip is added to a unique rule just for me. I do then reverse the order

```
sudo knock -v A.B.C.D 9000 8000 7000
```

from the client terminal and the rule applied just for me is being deleted, as it should. 
Well, the thing that doesn't work is the initial rule to block all requests from anywhere to any port except for port 80. I have been around this a lot of time, even tried to block all the traffic from everywhere with this rule:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

but nothing. Actually, I noticed that when a rule like this is applied, I am disconnected from the vps, where connected with ssl. Ok that's obvious but, the thing is that when disconnected and sending back to the server the

```
sudo knock -v A.B.C.D 7000 8000 9000
```

nothing happens. I mean, I am connected via VNC from host's management webpage and iptables don't refresh and obviously don't add the explicit rule for me and I am off. So guys, if anyone has to suggest anything to my issue or can help me, I would really appreciate it. I am burned with this from the morning and still nothing.
Thank you in advance.